# How to restart a remote Windows desktop when start menu is disabled?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, reboot, start-menu

I am working remotely via the Windows Remote Desktop app.  The start menu on the *remote* desktop has become non-responsive.  (I can't get a look at the calendar or the notifications either.  But all the other icons on the task bar seem OK.)  So, is there some way for me to re-boot the remote desktop?  I obviously can't use "restart" from the non-operable start menu!  When I try other methods I have found, my *home* desktop interprets them as telling *it*, not *the remote*, to re-boot.  Any ideas?  One more thing: I don't have admin privileges on the machine and can't much of anything beyond what can be done on the desktop.  For instance, ctrl-alt-del to get the task manager is a non-starter.

Comment: Try Winkey + X to see that menu, choose Admin Command prompt and shutdown /r   to restart it. Try that and see if it works for you

Comment: Does Windowskey-R still work ? Does right-click menu on teh desktop still work ?

Comment: @John  Thanks, but no go.

Comment: @Tonny  Windowskey-R, yes.  I can right-click in the main desktop, but right-click is not detected in the task bar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press <kbd>WIN</kbd>+ <kbd>R</kbd>, then run the command
`shutdown /s /t 0` to power off or
`shutdown /r /t 0` to restart your machine.

References:

- [shutdown](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown)
- [Windows Command Prompt - 6 sleep, shutdown, restart](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ToX5lbXmSgM)

Comment: I need to restart.  Would that be "shutdown -s -t 0 /r" ?

Comment: Why `-s` `-t` when the docs clearly say it would be `/s /t` etc ? Is this a specific Run command format? and why the enclosing quotes?

Comment: @tetsujin you're right. I was using the **old syntax** which I used so far. I updated my answer with **lastest syntax**.

Comment: @bob.scamento, "shutdown -s -t 0 /r" doesn't work because you're trying to use both parameters "-s" and "/r" but **"shutdown -s -t 0"** and **"shutdown /r /t0"** would work very well. "-" is the **old syntax** and the "/" is **new syntax** accord to with the [shutdown documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown). Just to use the cmd shutdown as I mentioned on my answer, I've just update it.

Answer (score 2):

If right-click on Desktop still works you can go directly to **

If not:Can you open ANY application that has a File-Open menu?
If so do that.
The File-Browser can be abused as a mini File-Explorer.

**
Navigate to the Desktop.
Right-click on the emtpy space (not an a file or a folder) and select New->Shortcut.
Set the application for the shortcut to `shutdown -s -t 0`.
Then double-click the shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way to shut down a Windows computer without needing to use the Start menu is by clicking on the desktop to focus on it and then pressing `Alt + F4`. This brings up the shutdown menu without having to go through the Start menu.

Also, if your Start menu is not responding, a quick fix for that would be to bring up the task manager by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + Esc`, going into the `Process` tab and ending the task named `explorer.exe`. This will close all your open folder windows and make the Taskbar disappear. You can enable it again by going into `File` -> `Run` and then entering `explorer.exe`.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try getting to the Task Manager the 'fast' way?
 <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>   <kbd>Esc</kbd> 
which saves having to go through the first screen.

Personally what I do for machines I need remote access to a lot is to put a couple of .bat files on the desktop, one for reboot, one for shutdown [using `shutdown.exe /g /f /t 00` or  `shutdown.exe /p /f`].
Saves all the messing around ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In RDP CTRL + ALT + END will send CTRL + ALT + DELETE to the RDP server.

Pressing ALT + F4 on the desktop in full screen mode (depending on your settings) will give you a screen to exit windows as well.